# Should reversing an NSMutableArray be avoided when possible?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, enumeration

Assume I have NSNumbers 1 - 450. I can choose to add them to an NSMutableArray either starting with 1 and ending with 450, or starting with 450 and ending with 1. My code would be a little simpler if I could start with 1 and end with 450, but when the time finally comes for me to enumerate over the array, I will ultimately need to reverse it. In other words, I need the first object in the enumeration to be 450, and the last one to be 1.

Since my code would be simpler if I do it this way (add starting with 1, then reverse it prior to enumeration), it's my preferred method. However, the Apple documentation for `- (NSEnumerator *)reverseObjectEnumerator` says:

> It is more efficient to use the fast enumeration protocol (see
>   NSFastEnumeration). Fast enumeration is available on Mac OS X v10.5
>   and later and iOS 2.0 and later.

So should I avoid the array reversal and simply write slightly more complicated code so that the NSMutableArray gets created in the desired order in the first place?

Comment: Check out Fast enumeration clarifications: How do you enumerate backwards? at http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/05/fast-enumeration-clarifications.html

Comment: You should probably show the code on this one, since it's hard to tell what kind of complications you're talking about in the array creation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use fast enumeration with an `NSEnumerator` instance, the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html) about fast enumeration even uses the `reverseObjectEnumerator:` method as an example:

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [array reverseObjectEnumerator];
for (NSString *element in enumerator) {
    //...
}
```

Besides, your question sounds a lot like premature optimization...

Comment: Thanks, I see now that I misunderstood the line in the documentation that caused me to raise this issue. It might seem like premature optimization, but I know that what I'm doing already has optimization issues because there are so many loops involved.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to write the more complicated code to put it in the right order. The reverseObjectEnumerator will work fine, it is only marginally slower. If performance is a big concern, either of the snippets below will work well (the faster of the two being the while loop)

```
// Assuming 'array' is your NSMutableArray
int i = [array count];
while(i--) {
  Object *current = [array objectAtIndex:i];
  // Mess around with current
}
```

That will start you at 450 and end at 0. You can also do this with a for loop, though you need to make sure that you either start with index 449, or you do something like

```
for(int i = [array count]; i > 0 ; i--) {
  Object *curreyt = [array objectAtIndex:i-1];
  // Mess around with current
}
```